# WPF Custom Control Menu Expand Functionality during Design-Time

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a Dropdown menu button that behaves like a Menu's MenuItem in XAML. I want the dropdown to automatically expand in the Designer view when a `MenuItem` is selected in XAML.

I've created a control that inherits from `MenuBase` so that it can contain menu items directly. I've looked over WPF Designer Extensibility, UIAutomation, and `Menu`/`MenuItem`'s code in dnSpy, but I can't seem to find anything that hints at how to create this behavior.

```
public class DropDownMenuButton : MenuBase
```

Comment: I advise against using Custom Controls in WPF. Usually those add a whole bunch of problems. Is there any reason you can not just use a Type Targetting Template?

Comment: The reason is I want a control that acts like a `Menu` containing a `MenuItem`, with the ItemsControl being for `MenuItems` contained by the original `MenuItem`. My current *working* implementation has to override the entire `MenuItem` template within the dropdown button's default style so that the `Menu` part is basically hidden and the contained root `MenuItem` looks like an actual button.

And I've never heard of anyone claiming custom controls are worthless in WPF. There's libraries dedicated to implementing controls that WPF does not include.

Comment: I never said they are "worthless". Please do not put claims like that into my mouth. It is just that 95% of the cases they do exactly the same thing as a Type Targetting Template, just adding more issues due to being a seperate GUI class.